# Couldn't suggest edit from iPad app

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, ios-app, ipad

I just tried to suggest an edit from the iPad app, but it said my account couldn't edit.

I was able to make the edit from the website (still on iPad).

Is there a known bug with suggesting edits?

Here's a link to the suggestion: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13171